# Linking cloud based MQTT Broker and local MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, iot, thingsboard

I am quite new to MQTT implementations. I am managing to connect popular cloud based MQTT Brokers such thingsboard.io, Azure and AWS to send Sensor information to create dashboards for monitoring devices.

**Problem**

I have installed a local things-board broker to my local computer. But it is unable to reach other dashboards on the internet. Is it possible? Or is it only accessible within the local network?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your doubt is more related to network connections. An MQTT broker will work in the same way, regardless it is working locally, in a fog server or in a cloud server. Obviously you will have to deal with access means: your clients/devices/applications must access the MQTT broker no matter where it is running. If you are running a local MQTT broker and it does not communicate directly with some cloud server, you can develop a specie of "gateway" only to send these data to the cloud or search for some tool that performs this task for you.

Below, you have some references regarding the working of MQTT and how to use it:

- [MQTT IoT Protocol complete tutorial - How it works with a demo](https://1sheeld.com/mqtt-protocol/)
- [Using local MQTT broker for cloud and interprocess communication](https://pagefault.blog/2017/03/02/using-local-mqtt-broker-for-cloud-and-interprocess-communication/)
- [MQTT Brokers/Servers and Cloud Hosting Guide](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-hosting-brokers-and-servers/)
- [Creating an MQTT Broker With CloudMQTT](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/create-mqtt-broker-cloudmqtt/)
- [How to setup your own MQTT Broker](https://obrienlabs.net/how-to-setup-your-own-mqtt-broker/)